# to parse chat conversations stored in a file

Tags: python

```
poem = '''\
me:hello dear
me:hyyy
asha:edaaaa
'''

f=open('poem.txt','r')
arr=[]
arr1=[]
varr=[]
darr=[]
i=0
j=1
for line in f.read().split('\n'):
    arr.append(line)
    i+=1
f.close()
#print arr[0]
#print arr[1]
#print arr[2]

text=arr[0].split(':')
#print text
line=text[0]
#print line
arr1.append(text[1])

for i in range(1,len(arr)):
    text=arr[i].split(':')
    if(line==text[0]):
        #print text[1]
        arr1.append(text[1])
    else:
        if(j==1):
            j+=1
            varr[j]=text[0] # this is not working
            darr[j]=text[1]
            print len(varr)
f.close()
print arr1
```

Comment: So this is homework for what course now?

Answer (score 5):

**CRYSTAL BALL MODE ON**

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)

with open('chat.log') as f:
    for line in f:
        nick, msg = line.split(':', 1)
        result[nick].append(msg)

print result
```

Comment: You didn't turn crystal ball mode off at the end! Who knows what unresolved references you may be leaving around!

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: The garbage collector should close it automatically :)

Comment: +1 for use of crystal ball.  Beyond that, my comments have nothing to do with the answer and everything to do with not being clear what problem @anu wants this to solve.  I'm not sure indexing messages by nick really gives you anything.  For one, the order of the messages, including the order relative to messages by other nicks, is probably important.  I can't see the resulting structure from this code being anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to assign to `varr[2]`, but `varr` is an empty list, so you would get an index error

There are a number of ways to fix this code, but it's not clear to me what the code is *supposed to do*

Nosklo's answer seemed reasonable to me, until I thought about it some more. I am not sure there is much point grouping the lines by the name since it means that the overall structure of the file is lost.

Here is how to simply parse the file into a `list` which you can manipulate later

```
result = []
with open('poem.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        result.append(line.partition(':')[::2])

print result
```

Comment: I _suspect_ (not sure) that the OP is trying to read lines and collect them into different arrays based on a part of the line (username, I presume).

Comment: @Manoj, you may be right, and it looks like nosklo agrees. I am not sure why the first line is treated specially or what the various arr, varr, darr represent though.